# How to use JSONparse without double quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have string `"field: 1, count: 22"` 
How parse to object?

eval not to offer

Comment: You might need to write your own parser.

Comment: To clarify Salman's comment: since that's not valid JSON, you cannot use a JSON parser.

Comment: You mean without using eval? You will nee some sort of eval

Comment: perhaps it will be easier to quote replace

Comment: You should split it and convert it to object .. No other way...

Answer (score 5):

If that is your real problem, unquoted keys. The following code might work (providing keys do not every include white space)

```
var x = "field: 1, count: 22";
JSON.parse("{"+x.replace(/([\S]+)\:/g,'"$1":')+"}");
```

But I think you really should be inspecting where your data is coming from and try and get that source to give you valid JSON, because as others have pointed out, what you have supplied, is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function getJSON(str){
      // get lines i.e. "field: 1"
      var lines = str.split(",");

      for (var i = lines.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // separate key from values. "[field, 1]"
            var keyValue = lines[i].split(": ");
            // add the quotes
            lines[i] = "\"" + keyValue[0] + "\": " + keyValue[1];
      }

      // replace single quotes with double quotes and join array with comma
      // parsing it to an JSON object
      return JSON.parse(("{" + lines.join(", ") + "}").replace(/'/g, "\""));
}
```

But @Forbesmyester 's solution is pretty good...
Anyway hope it help..